# Apply PHP regex replace on a multi-line repeated pattern

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have this input:

```
I can haz a listz0rs!
# 42
# 126
I can haz another list plox?
# Hello, world!
# Welcome!
```

I want to split it so that each set of hash-started lines becomes a list:

```
I can haz a listz0rs!
<ul>
    <li>42</li>
    <li>126</li>
</ul>
I can haz another list plox?
<ul>
    <li>Hello, world!</li>
    <li>Welcome!</li>
</ul>
```

If I run the input against the regex "/(?:(?:(?<=^# )(.*)$)+)/m", I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 42
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 126
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Hello, world!
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Welcome!
    )
)
```

This is fine and dandy, but it doesn't distinguish between the two different lists. I need a way to either make the quantifier return a concatenated string of all the occurrences, or, ideally, an array of all the occurrences.

Ideally, this should be my output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 42
        [1] => 126
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Hello, world!
        [1] => Welcome!
    )
)
```

Is there any way of achieving this, and if not, is there a close alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with regular expressions, you'll need two.  Use the regex `^(#.*\r?\n)+` to match each list and add tags around it.  Within each list (as matched by the first regex), search-and-replace `^#.*` with `<li>$0</li>` to add tags around each list item.  Both regexes require `^` to match at line breaks (`/m` flag in PHP).

In PHP you can use `preg_replace_callback` and `preg_replace` to achieve this in just a few lines of code.

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/^(#.*\r?\n)+/m', 'replacelist', $subject);

function replacelist($groups) {
  return "<ul>\n" .
    preg_replace('/^#.*/m', '    <li>$0</li>', $groups[0])
    . "</ul>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say don't try to do it all in a single regex - instead, first use a regex to match sets of consecutive lines that all begin with `#` signs and wrap those lines with a `<ul></ul>` pair. Then use a second regex (or not even a regex at all - you could just split on line breaks) to match each individual line and convert it to `<li></li>` format.

Comment: I thought of doing that as well, but the problem is that you can't quantify the lines, so when you wrap them in ul tags, you'll be wrapping *each* line instead of the entire set.

Comment: With a multiline regex, you could match multiple lines at once. You'd just need to match the whitespace newline characters between them too.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would:

1. explode("\n", $input) into an array where 1 key =  line
2. foreach through that array
3. whenever you get a line that doesn't start with a #, that's when you add your closing/opening ul tags

Add a little more to deal with unexpected input (like two non hash lines in a row) and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid regex altogether, and simply try a simpler approach by having it read the file, line by line (an array of lines), and every time it encounters a non-hash-started line, it starts a new list. Like so:

```
// You can get this by using file('filename') or 
// just doing an explode("\n", $input)
$lines = array(
    'I can haz a listz0rs!',
    '# 42',
    '# 126',
    'I can haz another list plox?',
    '# Hello, world!',
    '# Welcome!'
);

$hashline = false;
$lists = array();
$curlist = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if ($line[0] == '#')
        $curlist[] = $line;
    elseif ($hashline) {
        $lists[] = $curlist;
        $curlist = array();
        $hashline = false;
    }
}
```

A little clean-up may be in order, but hopefully it helps.

(after reading new answers, this is basically an indepth explanation of Syntax Error's answer.)

EDIT: You may want it to strip off the # at the beginning of each line too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748919/apply-php-regex-replace-on-a-multi-line-repeated-pattern/2748938#2748938) has already explained what I'm doing. But here goes the link to a [**working example**](http://www.ideone.com/Iixub).

Answer (score 0):

With structured content like this, I would not do this as a regex. How about another approach?

```
$your_text = <<<END
I can haz a listz0rs!
# 42
# 126
I can haz another list plox?
# Hello, world!
# Welcome!
END;

function printUnorderedList($temp) {
    if (count($temp)>0) {
        print "<ul>\n\t<li>" .implode("</li>\n\t<li>", $temp) . "</li>\n</ul>\n";
    }
}

$lines = explode("\n", $your_text);
$temp = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 1) == '#') {
        $temp[] = trim(substr($line,1));
    } else {
        printUnorderedList($temp);
        $temp = array();
        echo $line . "\n";
    }
}
printUnorderedList($temp);
```